# sweetalert disappear Instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

```
swal({
    title: "xxx",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    .....
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            swal("yes, do it!");
        } else {
            swal("cannel!");
        }
    }
);
```

in my page a button binding a js function , the function execute this code . On the page appear the "are you sure" confirm box when I click the button. but when I click yes , the next sweetalert just flushes and disappear instantly. what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the closing operation of the plugin uses a timer to do some cleanup, which is executed after 300ms, so the new alert also is getting cleaned up.

One hack to fix it is to use a timer like

```js
swal({
    title: "xxx",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true
  },
  function(isConfirm) {
    debugger;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (isConfirm) {
        swal("yes, do it!");
      } else {
        swal("cannel!");
      }
    }, 400)
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: It's four years later, but Google brought me here, and the answer underneath yours is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

**As the problem has been solved, consider this just an another approach.**

You can also use `event.preventDefault()` for the 2nd ***sweetalert***. I got stuck in the same situation, except that I only had 1 sweetalert to be displayed.

From [this mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault),

> The Event interface's preventDefault() method tells the user agent
>   that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action
>   should not be taken as it normally would be.

On clicking the submit button, it appeared for an instance and then I was directed to another page (specified in action attribute). Since this was happening by default, using `event.preventDefault()` made it stay.

Thanks for sharing your doubt !

Answer (score 2):

just add `event.preventDefault();` before swal function it will prevent it from disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

Set the closeonconfirm attribute to false i.e. `closeOnConfirm: false,`

Comment: This is a much better answer than the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once You calling to the function which is show the sweet alert make sure calling button type should keep as button not submit.

```
<form  method="post">                                 
 <button  type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-info" onclick="buy_harvest()">Buy</button>
                                            <button  type="submit" class="btn-wide btn-shadow btn btn-success" name="good_condition">Good condition</button>
                                            <button  type="submit" class="btn-wide btn btn-danger" name="inedible">Inedible</button>                                              </form>  

<script>
    function buy_harvest(){
       

    var { value: formValues } = Swal.fire({
        title: 'How mutch want to Buy?',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: `Buy`,
        html:
          '<div style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="buy_qty" style="width:150px;"><label> Quanity </label></div>' ,
          
        focusConfirm: false,
        preConfirm: () => {
          var buy_qty = document.getElementById("buy_qty").value;
          if(buy_qty!="" || buy_qty!=0){
           
            //call to another function and pass value
            process_buy(buy_qty);
          }       
        }
      })
    }
</script>
```